# using javascript onblur event for 1 row at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

Hey guys I am curious if I am able to change the form I have now to work one line at a time.
To start, this is the table I have.

Table:

```
<form name="form1" action="submit.php" method='POST'>
    <table border="0" class="signUp">
    <tr><td align="center" class= "signUpfont"> Sign up for FREE </td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" text="First Name" class='signUpinput' id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" onblur="validate();" /></td>
                <td><label id = "fnamelabel"></label></td>
            </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" class='signUpinput' id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" onblur="validate();" /></td>
                <td><label id = "lnamelabel"></label></td>
            </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" class='signUpinput' id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" onblur="validate();" /></td>
                <td><label id = "emaillabel"></label></td>
            </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" class='signUpinput' id="email2" name="email2"  placeholder="Re-enter Email" onblur="validate();" /></td>
                <td><label id = "email2label"></label></td>
            </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="password" class='signUpinput' id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Password" onblur="validate();" /></td>
                <td><label id = "passlabel"></label></td>
            </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" style="color:white; background-color:#2B4478; width: 100px;margin-left: 52px;"></td></tr>
```

This is my javascript:

```
    function validate()
{
var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var email2 = document.getElementById("email2").value;
var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;

var fname_reg = /^\w*$/;
var lname_reg = /^\w*$/;
var email_reg = /\w+\@\w+\.\w{1,3}/;
var pass_reg = /^\w*$/;

if(!fname_reg.test(fname) || fname == "")
{
document.getElementById("fnamelabel").innerHTML = '<img src="images/redcheckmark.png" height="25" width="25" />';
}else{
document.getElementById("fnamelabel").innerHTML = '<img src="images/checkmark.png" height="25" width="25" />';
}

if(!lname_reg.test(lname) || lname == "")
{
document.getElementById("lnamelabel").innerHTML = '<img src="images/redcheckmark.png" height="25" width="25" />';
}else{
document.getElementById("lnamelabel").innerHTML = '<img src="images/checkmark.png" height="25" width="25" />';
}

if(!email_reg.test(email) || email == "")
{
document.getElementById("emaillabel").innerHTML = '<img src="images/redcheckmark.png" height="25" width="25" />';
}else{
document.getElementById("emaillabel").innerHTML = '<img src="images/checkmark.png" height="25" width="25" />';
}

if(!email_reg.test(email2) || email2 != email || email2 == "")
{
document.getElementById("email2label").innerHTML = '<img src="images/redcheckmark.png" height="25" width="25" />';
}else{
document.getElementById("email2label").innerHTML = '<img src="images/checkmark.png" height="25" width="25" />';
}

if(!pass_reg.test(pass) || pass == "")
{
document.getElementById("passlabel").innerHTML = '<img src="images/redcheckmark.png" height="25" width="25" />';
}else{
document.getElementById("passlabel").innerHTML = '<img src="images/checkmark.png" height="25" width="25" />';
}

}

    </script>
```

Soo.. as of right now when I lose focus of the first input (first name).  It fills all of the boxes with a red checkmark because they are all empty.  Is there anyway I can make this event happen for only that one line that is losing focus at a time and have the rest with no green checkmark or red until it has been attempted to be filled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to make use of the `event.target` attribute (see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target) page from MDN). This value contains the DOM object on which the event occured. Your new validator would look something like this:

```
function validate(event) {
    if(!event.target) {
        return;
    }
    switch(event.target.id) {
          // perform individual checks
    }
}
```

This way, only the DOM object targetted by the event would have validation done on it.

Comment: Awesome information was exactly what I was looking for.  Marked as answer